# Input fields aren't clickable with textarea in form. Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason, when I add a text area to my form using bootstrap 3, the input fields become not clickable but if I take the textarea out they seem to work fine.

My Code:

```
<div class="row">
<form class="form col-lg-12" role="form">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <label for="Name">Your Name:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control cntct" placeholder="Name" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <label for="Email">Your Email Address:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control cntct" placeholder="Email" />
  </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <label class="msg" for="Message">Your Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-cntct">Send Your Message</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Anyone's help is greatly appreciated. If you need the link to see it live, the url is http://themelux.com/dev/YouSale/ you can view the contact form at the bottom of the page.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="form col-lg-12">
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
    <label for="Name">Your Name:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control cntct" placeholder="Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
    <label for="Email">Your Email Address:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control cntct" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 13px;margin-right: 13px;">
        <label class="msg" for="Message">Your Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-cntct">Send Your Message</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your class col-lg-6 a higher z-index then col-lg-12.

At the moment they are overlapping.

```
.col-lg-6 {
    z-index:5;
}

.col-lg-12 {
     z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The div containing your text area is on top of the div containing the text inputs.

your .col-lg-6 class is floating left and your .col-lg-12 class is not so it overlaps.

Add a float:left; to .col-lg-12 or else add a clear:left; to the div containing the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your form contents inside rows, in this case your textarea would be on its own row. There shouldn't be any need to mess with the css of columns etc. to do this, otherwise you might wonder why you're using a grid system in the first place.

Update with code:

```
<div class="row">
<form class="form col-lg-12" role="form">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
          <label for="Name">Your Name:</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control cntct" placeholder="Name" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
          <label for="Email">Your Email Address:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control cntct" placeholder="Email" />
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
          <label class="msg" for="Message">Your Message:</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-cntct">Send Your Message</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

It's not great markup (though it's better than before), but that's grid systems for you.